# Sine wave least squares curve fitting possible (using GSL)?

Tags: math, curve-fitting, gsl, least-squares

Is it possible to fit an A*sin(B*t+C) function with GSL or a similar library?

i want to get the A and C parameter of a sine wave present in 4096 samples (8bit) and can provide an good approximation of B.

A think that should be possible with GSLs non-linear multifit but I don’t understand the mathematical background with all that Jacobian matrix stuff...

Comment: For this special case, you might also use an FFT and look for the frequency B with maximal absolute value A of the amplitude. The phase C is then obtained from the phase of the complex amplitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

You have probably read this: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Overview-of-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html#Overview-of-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting

What is required from you is to provide two functions

the objective:

`

```
int sine_f (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, 
        gsl_vector * f){
    ...
    for(...){
    ...
      double Yi = A * sin(B*t +C);
      gsl_vector_set (f, i, (Yi - y[i])/sigma[i]);
    }
    ...
    }
```

and then the derivative of the objective with respect to the parameters

```
int
sine_df (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, 
         gsl_matrix * J)
//the derivatives of Asin(Bt +C) wrt A,B,C for each t
```

This is straight from
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html#Example-programs-for-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting

So the Jacobian is just a 3xN matrix, where N is the number of data points 
For example J(0,3) = sin(B*t_3 + C)

if A,B,C correspond to x[0],x[1],x[2]

And J(1,5) = A*t_5*cos(B*t_5 + C)
This is the derivative wrt. B

Comment: what is the purpose of the sigma[]-Vector? I see in the example it is initialised with 0.1?

Comment: I think it is the weights for each data point
f_i = ((A \exp(-\lambda t_i) + b) - y_i)/\sigma_i

I don't know why they set it to .1, since if all weights are the same (as in the example), then they don't factor into the minimization. It only makes sense if some data points have a higher accuracy than others, in which case they will have a lower sigma_i

Answer (score 0):

Thank you alexandre, you helped me a lot!

Here is the code I'am using now:

```
typedef struct{
  uint32    u32_n;
  float64*  pf64_y;
  float64*  pf64_sigma;
}ST_DATA;

int expb_f (const gsl_vector* x, void* p_data, gsl_vector* f)
{
    ST_DATA* pst_data = (ST_DATA*)p_data;
    uint32   u32_n      = pst_data->u32_n;
    float64* pf64_y     = pst_data->pf64_y;
    float64* pf64_sigma = pst_data->pf64_sigma;

    float64  A  = /* x[0] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    float64  B  = /* x[1] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 1);
    float64  C  = /* x[2] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 2);
    float64  Yi,Fi;
    uint32 i;
    for (i=0; i<u32_n; i++)
    {
        Yi = A * sin(B*i + C);
        Fi = (Yi - pf64_y[i])/pf64_sigma[i];
        /* f[i] = Fi; */    gsl_vector_set(f,i,Fi);
    }

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_df (const gsl_vector* x, void* p_data, gsl_matrix* J)
{
    ST_DATA* pst_data = (ST_DATA*)p_data;
    uint32   u32_n      = pst_data->u32_n;
    float64* pf64_y     = pst_data->pf64_y;
    float64* pf64_sigma = pst_data->pf64_sigma;

    float64  A  = /* x[0] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    float64  B  = /* x[1] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 1);
    float64  C  = /* x[2] */ gsl_vector_get (x, 2);
    float64  Yi;
    uint32 i;
    for (i=0; i<u32_n; i++)
    {
        /* J[i][0] =    sin(B*i+C);   */gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 0,   sin(B*i+C)  );
        /* J[i][1] =  A*cos(B*i+C)*i; */gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 1, A*cos(B*i+C)*i);
        /* J[i][2] =  A*cos(B*i+C);   */gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 2, A*cos(B*i+C)  );
    }
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_fdf (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_vector * f, gsl_matrix * J)
{
  expb_f(x, data, f);
  expb_df(x, data, J);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```